# How to enable usb debugging and install an apk to an android device with non-functioning display?

Tags: android

The display of my Xperia z3 is non-functioning(i.e. all I can see is a black screen) after an accidental damage due to water-insertion. But all other parts are working fine. The screen responses to touch, I can hear the touch sounds and I can click photographs as well with the camera key.

After connecting the phone with USB cable to my ubuntu laptop, I can browse through the internal storage files on the phone and locate the newly created image files as I click new photographs and take screen-shots. But I can't open any files(images/audio/videos) with errors like "couldn't load image" and "couldn't determine type of stream". However, I'm able to copy new files to the internal storage.

I want to install some screencasting application like vysor on my phone so that I can access it using my laptop. I know this can be done using adb commands but the problem here is that USB debugging is not enabled on my phone and hence I can't find it on the list of adb devices.

Is there any workaround for such situation?

Comment: See if you can unlock the bootloader and then root it. Then I think you might be able to enable usb debugging from the command line.

Comment: I'm not sure if I can unlock the bootloader with a non-functional display. If you know how to do it then please let me know @dazza5000

Comment: forgot about that part - im sorry - you might be able to look into an mhl connector if your phone supports hdmi output